# How to execute Zuora ZOQL query directly using REST API

Tags: rest, zuora, zuora-soap

zuora-soap API provides ZOQL through [query()](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/DC_Developers/G_SOAP_API/E_SOAP_API_Calls/query_call) and returns query results in that response itself.

I am looking for the same feature in zuora REST API. But it supports executing query through ["export"](https://www.zuora.com/developer/api-reference/#operation/Object_GETExport) or ["batch-query"](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/DC_Developers/T_Aggregate_Query_API/B_Submit_Query) api. Those API allows me to fetch the query results through another request using either by exportId or batchJobId.

But I am interested to received the query results in single request similar to zuora-soap. Is there any feature available in zuora REST API

Answer (score 1):

[`POST /v1/action/query`](https://www.zuora.com/developer/api-reference/#operation/Action_POSTquery) REST endpoint accepts ZOQL through `queryString` in JSON body. Here is an example HTTP request representing `select Id, Name from Account` ZOQL query

```
POST /v1/action/query HTTP/1.1
Host: rest.apisandbox.zuora.com
apiAccessKeyId: some@example.com
apiSecretAccessKey: ************
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "queryString": "select Id, Name from Account"
}
```

which returns

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "Name": "DP test sync account 1",
            "Id": "2c92c0f85fde706c015feef1b4ca6e11"
        },
        {
            "Name": "001g000001nHTIoAAO",
            "Id": "2c92c0f85fde706c015ffd8d488b5e46"
        },
        ...

    ],
    "queryLocator": "2c92c0f867067b440167087646951e86-2000",
    "size": 2239,
    "done": false
}
```

Comment: query() is a SOAP API. I am looking this exact feature in REST API